# Photo noise level in RAW format

Tags: raw, jpeg, noise, raw-vs-jpeg

Why is the noise level of raw photos higher than jpeg photos?
I have encountered this issue several times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically the software that creates the jpeg does some noise reduction.  There are often options on the camera for how much to do.  Software that works with raw photos usually has options for noise reduction, but starts out without any.  You get to choose how much you do.